# Class cannot be instantiated in xml

Tags: android, user-interface

I don't know why but my class cannot be instantiated in XML. Below is my Code. I tried everything, but nothing seems to be working. Tried invalidating cache and restarting , nothing works.

CustomFontTextView.java

```
public class CustomFontTextView extends  TextView {

    public static final String ANDROID_SCHEMA = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";



    public CustomFontTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        applyCustomFont(context, null);
    }

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray attributeArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.CustomFontTextView);

        String fontName = attributeArray.getString(R.styleable.CustomFontTextView_font);
        int textStyle = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_SCHEMA, "textStyle", Typeface.NORMAL);

        Typeface customFont = selectTypeface(context, fontName, textStyle);
        setTypeface(customFont);

        attributeArray.recycle();
    }

    private Typeface selectTypeface(Context context, String fontName, int textStyle) {
        if (fontName.contentEquals(context.getString(R.string.font_name_fontawesome))) {
            return FontCache.getTypeface("fontawesome.ttf", context);
        } else if (fontName.contentEquals(context.getString(R.string.font_name_source_sans_pro))) {
          /*
          information about the TextView textStyle:
          http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_textStyle
          */
            switch (textStyle) {
                case Typeface.BOLD: // bold
                    return FontCache.getTypeface("SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf", context);

                case Typeface.ITALIC: // italic
                    return FontCache.getTypeface("SourceSansPro-Italic.ttf", context);

                case Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC: // bold italic
                    return FontCache.getTypeface("SourceSansPro-BoldItalic.ttf", context);

                case Typeface.NORMAL: // regular
                default:
                    return FontCache.getTypeface("SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf", context);
            }
        } else {
            // no matching font found
            // return null so Android just uses the standard font (Roboto)
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

activity.main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="Reenath"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <com.trupik.virtualmall.activity.customfonts.CustomFontTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="Reenath"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:font="@string/font_name_source_sans_pro"/>

    <com.trupik.virtualmall.activity.customfonts.CustomFontTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="Reenath"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:font="@string/font_name_source_sans_pro"/>

    <com.trupik.virtualmall.activity.customfonts.CustomFontTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="Reenath"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:font="@string/font_name_fontawesome"/>

    <com.trupik.virtualmall.activity.customfonts.CustomFontTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="&#xf135;&#xf135;&#xf135;&#xf135;&#xf135;"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:font="@string/font_name_fontawesome"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "italic"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils_Delegate.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils_Delegate.java:72)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:93)
    at android.util.BridgeXmlPullAttributes.getAttributeIntValue(BridgeXmlPullAttributes.java:134)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeXmlBlockParser.getAttributeIntValue(BridgeXmlBlockParser.java:436)
    at com.trupik.virtualmall.activity.customfonts.CustomFontTextView.applyCustomFont(CustomFontTextView.java:41)
    at com.trupik.virtualmall.activity.customfonts.CustomFontTextView.<init>(CustomFontTextView.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor481.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:168)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Post your logcat please

Comment: Please have a look at my Logcat

Answer (score 0):

its hard to tell what is the issue without your `logcat`

Anyway if you just want to implement custom fonts I would suggest [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

its pretty simple and straight forward.

Hope it helps

Comment: I want to implement it in XML so I am choosing this way

Comment: Please have a look at my logcat

Comment: with library you will be able to implement it in xml in a better way

Answer (score 0):

The issue is raised from the following line in xml:

```
android:textStyle="italic"
```

So most probably the issue is in `selectTypeface` method. Check if you have handled `italic` properly there.

The problem should be solved but if the problem still exit, I cannot tell the exact reason as theoretically it should not create the issue but as it is causing the application to crash and you need to fix it on urgent basis, there may be a workaround for this.

In your `attrs` file, add following attribute in your `CustomFontTextView` styleable:

```
<attr name="textStyle">
    <flag name="normal" value="0" />
    <flag name="bold" value="1" />
    <flag name="italic" value="2" />
 </attr>
```

And in your `CustomFontTextView.java` class, change the following line:

```
int textStyle = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_SCHEMA, "textStyle", Typeface.NORMAL);
```

to

```
int textStyle = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.CustomFontTextView_textStyle, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

And in your layout xml files, change all `android:textStyle` to `app:textStyle`. Hope the solution works for you.